# Free rotating SVG point symbols

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have to rotate a great number of point SVG symbols (valves, caps, Te, etc.) in order to fit them with the gas distribution network. SVG rotating could be achieved by creating a field with angle attributes for each point, but this process is very long due to the great number of points.
Is there a tip or a plugin that permit the free rotation of symbols?

Comment: what do you mean by 'free rotation'?

Comment: Instead of using numeric angle value for each SVG point, I could rotate it interactly (like rotating a block in Autocad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a possibility to manually rotate symbols but you can rotate label.

So a workaround could be to label your point with your SVG, you need to set the label text as space, then add your SVG as a background (dont forget to set the rotation to ''Sync with label'') then in the placement tab use data defined rotation with your rotation field. Then you could use the rotation tool in the label toolbar (in edit mode) to automatically update your rotation field.

After you could just use the label as a symbology or use your updated rotation field in a classical data defined symbology

Comment: Thank you for your email. Could you please illustrate these steps by screen capture for a better understanding?

Comment: Now, it works perfectly. Very clever tips. Many thanks.